# What's the word that refers to markets where cheap, often used, goods are sold?

Tags: word-request

What's the word that refers to markets where cheap, often used, goods are sold? I forgot the word that refers to such market. Also, if you know the word, is there an alternate way to refer to it, I remember it was called a ___ market, but I would rather use a single word if that's possible. I am sure they don't really exist anymore because of eBay and Amazon.

Comment: Have you consulted a bilingual dictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're called *flea markets* and they still exist and in some locations even thrive, despite the growth of online markets.

> a usually open-air market for secondhand articles and antiques

(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flea%20market))